VannaAI documentation code is depreacted ( im getting error when i run their code)
im getting this error
line 1, in <module>
from vanna import OpenAI_Chat
ImportError: cannot import name 'OpenAI_Chat' from 'vanna'

when i runt this code
from vanna import OpenAI_Chat
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from vanna import ChromaDB_VectorStore

client = AzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint = "https://example-gpt.openai.azure.com/", 
  api_key="api key",  
  api_version="2024-02-01"
)
class MyVanna(ChromaDB_VectorStore, OpenAI_Chat):
    def __init__(self, config=None):
        ChromaDB_VectorStore.__init__(self, config=config)
        OpenAI_Chat.__init__(self, client=client, config=config) 

i did install vanna using pip install 'vanna[chromadb,openai]'
EDIT:
i updated the import
from vanna.openai.openai_chat import OpenAI_Chat
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from vanna.chromadb.chromadb_vector import ChromaDB_VectorStore

and now it's working thx for @Jared Smith

Did you read the docs at all? Looks like you want from vanna.openai.openai_chat import OpenAI_Chat.

i got my code from vannaai documentation , thx it's working .

Then please post a link to it in your question. When I google "vanna python ai" and it takes me to a github README with an example clearly different than your question code it makes it look like you just didn't bother to do even a single google search's worth of due dilligence before posting. That will not help your question be well-received. Also, glad you got it sorted!

Seriously though, sounds like their documentation may be inconsistent. Would be very nice of you to submit a PR to fix that for them!
